# Android html5 game webview slow

Tags: html, webview, chromium

I'm trying to insert an html5 game into a webview of an Android 4.2 app but the performances are weak.
I've tried with "hardware acceleration" and to set the webview settings in many ways.
I heard about the Chromium library but I don't know where to find and how to implement it. 
Pleae help me.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what you've done regarding hardware acceleration? Also, while the Chrome engine might be relatively faster it's not going to overcome the major differences in computing/graphical power between desktop and mobile device.  If you're game is poor performing switching engines most likely isn't the main problem.  JavaScript performance overall is a good place to start.

Comment: We added the property android:hardwareAccelerated in the manifest file (I saw this in another post).
Is there a way to have better performance in your opinion?

Comment: It depends on what you are animating really.  If you are using CSS then you also will need to use proper hardware-accelerated prefixes in applicable CSS properties.  Not all of them are accelerated.  And even with that you need to be careful how many DOM elements are animated at one time.  The processing power on small devices is still rather limited.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the Crosswalk:
  https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk

it's a HTML5 runtime framework base on Chromium, it takes advantage of Chromium and has much better  HTML5 performance (WebGL/Canvas/CSS3) than native WebView.

https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/samples/webgl

Answer (score 2):

If it is a html5 canvas game, try addig this to your canvas element in css (boosted performance in my game):

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This has been the only speedhack that really had a effect on my webview. But be careful not to overuse it! (you can read more about the hack in [this article](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/03/11/performance-ux-considerations-for-successful-phonegap-apps/).)

And as Shouqon mentioned, check out crosswalk.

Comment: Dude, this is what I was looking for! Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there was a bug for this specific use case that supposedly was fixed in 4.4.3: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315111

Try it with the newer version and see if it doesn't go away.